# Application not installing some device Android os N android

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat, android-os-handler

I have samsung device s7 edge. Application not installed for live build. Please help me, what is an exactly problem. See this error throw, on Android N os in device.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your manifest file, add the  element and specify the **`android:xlargeScreens`** attribute to **"true"**:

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

> If your app targets API level 24 or higher, you can configure how and
>   whether your app's activities support multi-window display. You can
>   set attributes in your manifest to control both size and layout. A
>   root activity's attribute settings apply to all activities within its
>   task stack.

```
android:resizeableActivity="true"
```

Read **[android:resizeableActivity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html)**

**FYI**

> If you build a multi-orientation app that targets API level 23 or
>   lower, and the user uses the app in multi-window mode, the system
>   forcibly resizes the app. The system presents a dialog box warning the
>   user that the app may behave unexpectedly. The system does not resize
>   fixed-orientation apps; if the user attempts to open a
>   fixed-orientation app under multi-window mode, the app takes over the
>   whole screen.

```
<application
....
 android:resizeableActivity="true">
```

Comment: @NajibPuthawala Glad to hear .

Comment: Thanks and Voted !

Comment: Could you please tell me why this alert message meant for? How can I hide the alert?

Answer (score 1):

try this it may work for you

In your manifest file, add the `<supports-screens>` element and specify the 
`android:xlargeScreens attribute to "true":`

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

In your manifest's `<uses-sdk>` element, set `android:targetSdkVersion` to `"11"` or higher:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

for more assistance please look into this page [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html)

Comment: Well, For this problem `android:resizeableActivity` create vital role .